# Packing all UV Islands when Draw Other Objects is activated?

Tags: uv, export, objects

I wanted to pack all UV islands from separated meshes at the same time 
while the Draw other Objects function is activated.

I already know the function to join the meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, but I get size changes when importing that mesh into the other tool. It is crucial for the other programs I use that the meshes don't get altered (aka joined).

Is there a function to pack all Islands from the meshes with the given limitation?

[image: can't pack all UV islands from separated Meshes.]